# Hibernate JoinColumn Error on not null constraint

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

Here's a list of my classes

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class JpaModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name ="ID", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

The Product Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_PRODUCT")
public class Product extends JpaModel{

    @Column(name= "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURER")
    private String manufacturer;

    /**
     * Work around for missing
     */
    @OneToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private InventoryItemPicture picture;
```

....
}

and the inventory item picture entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TXN_INVENTORY_PICTURE")
public class InventoryItemPicture extends JpaModel{

    @Column
    private byte[] image;

    @Column
    private String fileName;
```

When saving the Product, The inventoryItemPicture is Optional, thus there will be times that it will be of null value, which is something I would want to happen. However upon saving the Product Entity with a null value this error shows up.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, test, dsadas, sdas, dsadsa, 500.00, 1000.00, 1500.00, 5, PRODUCT).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementProxy.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 120 more
```

Comment: where is you id column, please added to the code

Answer (score 5):

From your log, it shows `id=null`, which is not related to inventoryItemPicture at all.

The issue is at `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Your log shows you are using postgresql, but "IDENTITY" can only be used for these dbs:

- Sybase, My SQL, MS SQL Server, DB2 and HypersonicSQL.

You should use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, which is supported by:

- Oracle, DB2, SAP DB, Postgre SQL or McKoi.

Try change your code to this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Comment: You have two nulls in log, check out if you set another value. Also, your query is "executeUpdate", if it's new object, you should use save() or persist().