# Spring Data JPA "null value in column xxx violates not-null constraint" on serial column with postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My entity has a mapOrder field which I want auto-increment like below:

```
@Entity
public class Map{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long mapOrder;

    //.......
}
```

The sql generated seems good:

```
CREATE TABLE map
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  map_order serial NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

But when I save it with Spring Data JPA's repository, like this:

```
Map m=new Map();
repo.save(m);
```

will give me exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "map_order" violates not-null constraint
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979746/mapping-postgresql-serial-type-with-hibernate-annotations

Comment: you are using object Long, so default value is null. Also you have to specify the generation method for map_order

Comment: @user3707125 Thanks, the accepted answer works for me, though ```@Generated``` is not a JPA annotation.

Answer (score 6):

[`@GeneratedValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) works with identifiers and you can't use it with regular fields.

You can, for example, use some object for sequences (with any key generation strategy):

```
@Entity
public class JpaNoPkSequence {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)    
    private Long id;
}
```

For using the strategy [`GenerationType.SEQUENCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#SEQUENCE) the sequence should be created in the database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE JPA_PK_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
ALTER SEQUENCE "JPA_PK_SEQ" OWNER TO something;
```

This should be specified in the key definition. You should also add a `one-to-one` relationship with the object that you will use to obtain sequences for regular fields:

```
@Entity 
public class Map {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="jpaPkSeq", sequenceName="JPA_PK_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jpaPkSeq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne           
    private JpaNoPkSequence sequence;
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your code to this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29028369

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the error was in creating the table.

You need to use `SERIAL` type instead of others (at least in Postgres).

**Before** (bigint type)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample_table

(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

**After** (serial type)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample_table

(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

The id in the entity class looked like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is full of bad advice. The problem is the second column with a serial value. The problem is that Hibernate explicitly inserts a null there. You have to tell it not to.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial", insertable = false)
private Long mapOrder;
```