# Can't add and update values using Spring Boot connecting to PostgreSQL database

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update a 'Student' from PostgreSQL Database, but it only deletes the old value and creates a new id value for the new Student, with all the other fields empty.

Here is the class for "Student", from "Persistence" package, "Entity" subpackage:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "student")

public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="student_id_seq", sequenceName = "student_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column
private String studentName;

@Column
private Integer studentGroup;

@Column
private String courseName;

@Column
private Integer studentGrades;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String name) {
    this.studentName = name;
}

public Integer getStudentGroup() {
    return studentGroup;
}

public void setStudentGroup(Integer group) {
    this.studentGroup = group;
}

public String getCourseName() { return courseName;}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {this.courseName = courseName;}

public Integer getStudentGrades() {
    return studentGrades;
}

public void setStudentGrades(Integer grades) {
    this.studentGrades = grades;
}
}
```

This is how my interface for "Repository" subpackage (also from "Persistence" package) looks like :

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {}
```

In "StudentService" ("Business" package) I have the operations for create, update, delete and view all the students I have :

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

@Inject
StudentRepository studentRepository;

public List<Student> getAllStudentssWithCourses()
{
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}

public Student create(Student newStudent)
{
    return studentRepository.save(newStudent);
}

public void update(Student newStudent, Student oldStudent){
    if(oldStudent == null){
        System.out.println("ERROR! Student does not exist !!!");
    } else{
        newStudent.setId(oldStudent.getId());
        newStudent.setStudentName(newStudent.getStudentName());
        newStudent.setStudentGroup(newStudent.getStudentGroup());
        newStudent.setCourseName(newStudent.getCourseName());
        newStudent.setStudentGrades(newStudent.getStudentGrades());
        studentRepository.save(newStudent);
    }
}


public void delete(Student student){
    studentRepository.delete(student);
}
}
```

In "Controller" package, I have :

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

@Inject
StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getStudents()
{
    List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudentssWithCourses();

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("student_view");
    mav.addObject("studentsWithCoursesList", studentList);
    mav.addObject("newStudent", new Student());
    return mav;

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postStudent(@RequestParam(value = "action") String action,@ModelAttribute(value = "newStudent") Student newStudent)
{
    if(action.equals("Create Student"))
        studentService.create(newStudent);
    else if(action.equals("Update Student"))
        studentService.update(new Student(), newStudent);
    else
        studentService.delete(newStudent);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:student");
}
}
```

My "student_view" in html looks like :

```
 <body background = "https://www.itmagazine.us/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/6f6499a403cf64afea180b6419def4ef.jpg">

 <h1>Welcome, student user !</h1>
 <table  border="1">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>student.ID</th>
  <th>student.NAME</th>
  <th>student.GROUP</th>
  <th>student.COURSE</th>
  <th>student.GRADES</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr th:each="student : ${ studentsWithCoursesList }">

  <td th:text="${ student.id }">ID</td>
  <td th:text="${ student.studentName }"></td>
  <td th:text="${ student.studentGroup }"></td>
  <td th:text="${ student.courseName }"></td>
  <td th:text="${ student.studentGrades }"></td>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>

  <form   th:object="${newStudent}" method = "POST">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Student ID</label>
    <input type = "text" th:field="*{id}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Student Name</label>
    <input type = "text" th:field="*{studentName}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Student Group</label>
    <input type = "text" th:field="*{studentGroup}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Course Name</label>
    <input type = "text" th:field="*{courseName}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label>Student Grades</label>
    <input type = "text" th:field="*{studentGrades}"/>
  </div>

 <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" name = "action" value="Create Student">ADD Student</button>
 <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" name = "action" value="Update Student">EDIT Student</button>
 <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary" name = "action" value="Delete Student">DELETE Student</button>
 </form>
 </body>
```

My main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication()

public class Assignment2 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       SpringApplication.run(Assignment2.class, args);

   }
}
```

In my "application.properties", I have :

```
spring.jpa.database = POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true


spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ps2
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.thymeleaf.cache = false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

server.port = 8090
```

My database in PostgreSQL :

```
CREATE TABLE public.student
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    student_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    student_group integer,
    course_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    student_grades integer,
    CONSTRAINT "Student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.student
OWNER to postgres;
-----
CREATE SEQUENCE public.student_id_seq;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.student_id_seq
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Finally, in "pom.xml", I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo1</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GenerationType.IDENTITY relies on a database auto-increment column to generate the id.

Your Student.id column in the dB is clearly not auto-increment.

I believe that standard syntax for auto-increment is available since Postgres10

[PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

See also https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/ for an intro on different generation strategies.
And the following question [How to choose the id generation strategy when using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041938/how-to-choose-the-id-generation-strategy-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate)

Summing up SEQUENCE is the best available option,
IDENTITY is only a good choice when you cannot use SEQUENCE because it disables JDBC batch updates.

Comment: I changed from IDENTITY into SEQUENCE and it still doesn't work. Is there a way to change my primary key and make it auto-increment?

Comment: Try specifying sequence name with @SequenceGenerator. Also, create this sequence in SQL.

Comment: It worked, but now I can't update any field in my table. It just deletes the old student and creates a new one, only with an incremented id and the rest of fields are empty.

Comment: Your update in studentService is wrong. Check what you are passing to this method as newStudent. Tip: check the implementation of save in your repository. It calls persist or merge depending on the id (null or not null) You dont need a special case for update. You don't need to delete anything to update.

Answer (score 0):

this question was already asked before.

In conclusion, you should use :

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`

It's because IDENTITY can only be used for these dbs:

Sybase, My SQL, MS SQL Server, DB2 and HypersonicSQL.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29028369/6884722

Comment: I changed from IDENTITY into SEQUENCE and now I have : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]